# Using html pages to navigate documents on shared drive

Tags: html

I do not have any experience with web development, so I'd really appreciate an advice on the following issue: 
a team of about 10 users currently has lost of documentation (mainly MS Office files and PDFs) on a shared drive, organized into folders. They want to keep it there, but at the same time want to have some very simple system that would allow them to navigate documentation in a more efficient manner. They cannot install any s/w on that computer. 
Would a few simple html files on the same shared drive, with some links to each other and links to relevant documents in each work? 
The issue is that, as I mentioned I do not have any experience, so I do not know what possible problems may appear if we just create these pages, put them on that shared drive and share link to the main page with everyone in the office. So, comments/suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop navigation kind of stuff,either you have to implement any server side coding in your application or any jquery plugins.

**http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/**

visit the above site.It is offering a set of jquery plugins and most of them are free.This will help you to achieve your functionality.